# Design watch UI like activity app's change the daily move goal screen

Tags: ios, user-interface, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

How to create watch UI like changing the daily move goal screen in the activity app?. Please refer the attached image file.  I should be able to change the number using watch digital crown as well as + and - icon.  Can somebody help me to create the similar UI ? [refer the UI component marked with red border in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkguP.jpg)

I achieved the component by placing button(for -),label(for count value) and button(for +) on the group and added the logic in the each button action. But I would like to change the count value using digital crown.  Is it possible to access the digital crown programmatically?

Comment: I am not getting !! What do you mean ?

Comment: What I mean is that you should show what *you* have tried to achieve said goal before asking for external help. If you have not try anything yet, then it is time to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access the digital crown. Set up a `WKInterfacePicker` and run its `focus()` method. Then, as the digital crown is rotated, `pickerChanged()` will provide its currently selected value.